# Access denied for user root after default installation

Tags: command-line, mysql, password

I see this when I ssh to my Ubuntu server:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1018-aws x86_64)
```

After installing mysql, I try to login to the mysql server but for some reason it asks me for a password that I do not have. So, I ran the following commands to uninstall mysql and reinstall.

Uninstall

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The I used [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04) link as guide to install mysql, and the commands went as follows:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo systemctl start mysql.service
```

When I run:

```bash
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

The prompt asks me to “Enter password for the user root”. Where do I find this password?

The idea of the command is to set the password.

How can I install mysql in this server to then be able to manage my databases?

I recently tried the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run) question, but it just lead me to the same error.

Comment: Have you try just pressing *Enter* key ? Leaves the password blank

Comment: Yes. Its after pressing enter without entering the password that I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is a bit strange. The final command creates a number of security restrictions. One of which is that you can only connect as the MySQL root user from the linux root user. If do **sudo -s** you will get a shell to root, and then you can connect to MySQL.

When you do, the only thing you should do is create a new MySQL user, grant it the privs it needs. May be also create a new DB and grant your new user access to that db.